# Packaging my angular 2 project dist folder as an asset bundle for dropwizard application

Tags: angular, maven, angular-cli, dropwizard

I am currently using angular2 with dropwizard .

By default Dropwizard application looks up an asset bundle from src/main/resources within the project module.

I am currently using angular2 and angular-cli to create angular builds. The angular cli's `ng build` command  generates the javascripts in the **dist** folder that is outside the src folder.

1. How can I make dist folder available for dropwizard to be able to serve it as an asset bundle?
2. Which maven plugins can I use to accomplish the above and create a jar that is available for dropwizard to serve from classpath?

Thanks

Comment: You can tell `ng build` to output to a different directory - use the `--output-path` flag.

Comment: @megan Can you explain me how did you create angular project in maven ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the build directory by editing the `outDir` in your `.angular-cli.json`

**.angular-cli.json**

```
 {
  ...
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "src/main/resources",
      ...
    }
   ]
  ...
}
```

See [Angular CLI Config Schema](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli) for all the angular-cli options.